# list of item drops down to show a list

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a list ever item in that list will have an arrow-down and on clicking on that arrow in 1st item an sub list with check box will drop down. and on clicking 2nd item in the main list sublist of the 1st list should get closed and sublist of 2n item should get displayed.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-label>'Sex'</ion-label>
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-forward" (click)="arrowdown()" *ngIf="dropdown"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="ios-arrow-down" (click)="arrowRight()" *ngIf="!dropdown"></ion-icon>
</ion-row>
 <ion-row >
      <ion-col *ngIf="!dropdown">
        <ion-item  *ngFor=" let item of GetTags; let i=index ">
           <ion-label>{{item.Sex}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox color="dark"></ion-checkbox>
         </ion-item>  
       </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
```

in this way i have 3 more grid with different value like color,size etc

```
dropdown: boolean = true;

 arrowdown(){
        this.dropdown = false;
    }
    arrowRight(){
        this.dropdown = true;
    }

dropdownModel = [
    {
        size: 1,
        label: 'Dresses',
        selected: false, // optional
        color: '#336699' // optional
    },
    {
        size: 2,
        label: 'Jeans',
        selected: false, // optional
        color: '#336699' // optional
    },
    {
        size: 3,
        label: 'Bags',
        selected: false, // optional
        color: '#336699' // optional
    },
    {
        size: 4,
        label: 'Blazzer',
        selected: false, 
        color: '#336699' 
    }

];
```

Comment: why are you using *ngIf instead of ng-if?

Comment: wrong tag, this is related to *angular* and not *angularjs*

Comment: saw it  here https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf @JohnVandivier